# How to count items in nested array of mongo document using spring data?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I have to count the number of `properties` my `Product` has. I am using following document structure:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("0000000000000000000002"),
    "name" : "Test",
    "properties" : [

        ObjectId("0000000000000000000003"),
        ObjectId("0000000000000000000004")

          ]
}
```

How to do it?

**Update:**

My try:

```
...
@Autowired
    private MongoOperations mongoOperations;
...
mongoOperations.aggregate(
                new BasicQuery("{$match: {\"_id\" : " + new ObjectId(productId) + "}}," +
                        "{$unwind: \"$properties\"}," +
                        "{$project: {count:{$add:1}}}," +
                        "{$group: {_id: null, number: {$sum: \"$count\" }}} "),
                        Product.class);
```

I am getting error from IDE:

```
aggregate in MaongoOperations cannot be applied to or.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.BasicQuery
```

How to fix it? Is it the easiest way to count properties using Sparing data?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MongoDB version 2.6 or later, you can make user of the [$size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size) aggregation operator to get the array size:

```js
db.products.aggregate(
   [
      {
         $project: {
            name: 1,
            numberOfProperties: { $size: "$properties" }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

Comment: Can you provide working Java code sample making use of Spring data?

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?  I can provide Java code sample, but I haven't used Spring Data yet.